# Testng.xml file is able to run tests as suite but running individual tests inside class file is failing to run

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

As shown below I have a TestNG selenium project which has BaseTest class which is extended to TestClass and there are 2 tests/methods TestA and TestB. When I run testng.xml file I am able to run suite successfully but running test individually on TestA or TestB or TestClass level, tests are not running

Project structure:

- Tests/TestClass (it has 2 methods TestA and TestB)
- pom.xml
- testng.xml
- PageObjects
- Reports
- Base/BaseTest

**testng.xml file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Automation Test Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener
            class-name="com.listeners.TestListener" />
    </listeners>
        
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <parameter name="env" value="QA"/>
  
    <test name="Functional Tests">
      <classes>
          <class name="com.tests.functional.TestScenario_001"/>
      </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**BaseClass:**

```java
public class BaseTest extends BaseClass
{
    @Parameters({"browser","env"})
    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUp(String browser, String env) throws IOException
    {
      startSession(browser,env);
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown() throws IOException
    {
      endSession();
    }
}
```

I tried adding `alwaysRun = true` at Before/After class methods but no luck. `startSession` and `endSession` methods will create driver instance and kill driver instance

**Getting error on console as below:**

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass com.base.BaseTest.setUp
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'browser' is required by BeforeClass on method setUp but has not been marked @Optional or defined
in /private/var/folders/0l/8yzm1t0d6dv86g62b9g27sc80000gp/T/testng-eclipse-421234397/testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass com.base.BaseTest.tearDown
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.close()" because "com.wrappers.BaseClass.driver" is null

FAILED: com.tests.functional.TestScenario_001.HelloWorld1
        Test description of HelloWorld1
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```